# OpenGL default framebuffer cleared at initialization?

Tags: opengl, framebuffer

Is it mentioned anywhere in the GL specification that the default framebuffer, created along with the context, has to be cleared (or already clear)?

I can't seem to find any info about this, so I assume that it is implementation defined.

Comment: If it's not stated in the docs, then you have to assume that the buffers are not cleared.